# API Dribbble not working to fetch attachments

Tags: dribbble-api

I'm using the V2 Dribbble API and it's working well... With a small twist, if it succeed at fetching the information about the shot, it doesn't fetch all the attachments for some reason...

Did I have to be pro for that ? Is there something special that I must do ?

Thanks so much in advance !

I've tried to delete and create a new project, put alt in images or else but nothing works